# iPhone 11 keeps rebooting and won’t let me update

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

My iPhone 11 keeps Ree booting and won’t let me update please can someone help every time I try upgrade it reboots it’s self

Comment: How do you try to apply the update, directly on the phone or via iTunes/Mac?

Comment: How long is the update running when the phone reboots (or better in which step of the update process does the reboot happen)?